# How to refresh the parent screen and get old state values when using Goback function from child screen Reach Navigation Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

i am using hooks and setting state values. I have 2 screens. When i come back from screen2 using goback() to screen1, i need to get the old state values which were hard coded.

Comment: Now, what you are getting? other than the old state?

Comment: basically on screen1 i have a country selector screen, user selects a country and then on press he reaches screen 2 where that countries info is displayed. when i goback if i select the same country again code works but when i select another it gives error. The countries are get using fetch from an api

Comment: please provide a sample code of screen1. so that it should be easy to figure it out

Comment: ok i am adding it in post

Comment: its not letting me edit the post says post is mostly code. Should i add a snack link where u could see the code?

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });
  }
Try to use focus listner on screen1

Comment: componentdidmount and componentdidunmount are not available in hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [React navigation events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        // do something
      });

      return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: should i add const unsubscribe and return unsubsribe to my code?

Comment: please provide a snack link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-nightingale-4r6r3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: just includes screen1